# PHP MySQL insert file, validating form with IF-statement with OR operator

Tags: php, mysql, forms, validation, if-statement

I am brand new to PHP and I am not sure if my technique is even good practice, but my code worked until I added the `|| (!is_numeric($variable))` portions of my if-statements.

I tested to code by inserting letters into the number fields but ensuring that the length of the string was correct. When I do, the code runs the else-statement and echos ".$jname."added.....etc"". The `mysqli_query` is commented out for testing. I have tried different versions with more or less parenthesis.

Why won't `is_numeric()` catch my letters? Am I allowed to do multiple ! arguments in an if-statement?

```
<?Php
    header('Refresh: 3; url=../job_table.php');
    require 'connect.php';  
    $jname = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['field1']);
    $jname_length = 25;
    $jwo = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['field2']);
    $jwo_length = 7;
    $jpo = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['field3']);
    $jpo_length = 4;
    $add_job_query = "INSERT INTO jobs (name, wo_no, po_no) VALUES ('$jname','$jwo','$jpo')";
    if(($jname || $jwo || $jpo ) == "") {
        echo "<center><h1>Please fill all fields!</h1></center>";
    } elseif(!(strlen($jname) <= $jname_length)) {
        echo "<center><h1>Name must be less than or equal to ".$jname_length." characters!</h1></center>";
    } elseif((strlen($jwo) != $jwo_length) || (!is_numeric($jwo))) {
        echo "<center><h1>WO number must be a ".$jwo_length." digit number!</h1></center>";
    } elseif((strlen($jpo) != $jpo_length) || (!is_numeric($jwo))) {
        echo "<center><h1>PO number must be a ".$jpo_length." digit number!</h1></center>";
    } else {
        //echo mysqli_query($db,$add_job_query);
        echo "<center><h1>".$jname." added!</h1><h1>WO number:".$jwo."</h1><h1>PO number:".$jpo."</h1></center>";
    }
    echo "<center><h1>Please wait.</h1></center>";
?>
```

Comment: change `if(($jname || $jwo || $jpo ) == ""){` to `if($jname =='' || $jwo == '' || $jpo  == ''){`

Comment: with each OR you have to give the code something to evaluate against.

Comment: You're checking `strlen` and `is_numeric`, is it supposed to be a string or integer?

Comment: It is supposed to be an integer, from what I've read strlen() seems to be the common way of counting digits. I would love to know other ways of figuring it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to me that you need something like this instead.

```
if(empty($jname) || empty($jwo) || empty($jpo)){
    echo "<center><h1>Please fill all fields!</h1></center>";
}elseif($jname <= $jname_length){
    echo "<center><h1>Name must be less than or equal to ".$jname_length." characters!</h1></center>";
}elseif(($jwo != $jwo_length) || (!is_numeric($jwo))){
    echo "<center><h1>WO number must be a ".$jwo_length." digit number!</h1></center>";
}elseif(($jpo != $jpo_length) || (!is_numeric($jwo))){
    echo "<center><h1>PO number must be a ".$jpo_length." digit number!</h1></center>";
}else{
    //echo mysqli_query($db,$add_job_query);
    echo "<center><h1>".$jname." added!</h1><h1>WO number:".$jwo."</h1><h1>PO number:".$jpo."</h1></center>";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, after seeing your comment I read the documentation again and understand it better. Seems obvious now that I need to put complete arguments between operators.